# How come the child process spawn works on window but not on ubuntu?

Tags: node.js

I am struggling running a command using spawn on ubuntu. I am using [vrp-cli](https://crates.io/crates/vrp-cli/1.2.4) module written with Rust, here is the code where i am trying to pass few arguments into spawn and run the command:

```
const Process = require("child_process").spawn('vrp-cli', 'solve pragmatic vrps/problem.json  vrps/solution.json -g vrps/solution.geojson');
```

and I am getting an error:

```
The subcommand 'solve
pragmatic' wasn't recognized
        Did you mean 'solve'?
If you believe you received this message in error, try re-run
ning with 'vrp-cli -- solve
pragmatic'
USAGE:
    vrp-cli [SUBCOMMAND]
For more information try --help
```

But when I am running same code with **one argument**(on ubuntu):

```
const Process = require("child_process")('vrp-cli', '-h');
```

Its working...

Same line code with more than one argument i am running on windows and its working with no problems:

```
const Process = require("child_process").spawn(`cmd`,`/K`,'solve pragmatic vrps/problem.json  vrps/solution.json -g vrps/solution.geojson');
```

So why do you think providing one argument in spawn is working but when i have more than one argument i am getting an error? Some how on windows its working fine but not on ubuntu.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the syntax for running command which have multiple arguments, for sample : 'ls -lrth /usr'

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const outputLs = spawn('ls', ['-lrth', '/usr']);

outputLs.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

outputLs.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(data.toString());
});

outputLs.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Also, first try to check the command normally on shell, does it work on Ubuntu systems? For your command, you should do something like this:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const outputLs = spawn('vrp-cli', ['solve', 'pragmatic', 'vrps/problem.json', 'vrps/solution.json', '-g', 'vrps/solution.geojson']);

outputLs.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

outputLs.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(data.toString());
});

outputLs.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

You need to pass all the arguments in an Array separated like above.

Comment: You are amazing!!! You are right, on ubuntu if I pass the arguments as array rather as a string, its working!!!